# Encryption of text containing tables and structures

Tags: java, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

i am encrypting decrypting files via certificates from local repo in java.
But for word processing files containing tables , diagrams the files doesnt remain same as the actual . I am using normal file Input/ output stream.
Any help will be useful thanks .

```
public int encryptFileWithpubkey(String filepath,PublicKey pubkey){
    int retval=0;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    File file=null;
    final String location = filepath;
    PublicKey pubKey= pubkey;
    try{
    try {
        fis = AccessController.doPrivileged(
         new PrivilegedExceptionAction<FileInputStream>() {
             public FileInputStream run() throws FileNotFoundException {

                 return new FileInputStream(location);
             }
         });
     } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
         throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getException();
     }
        InputStream is =  fis;
      //long length = file.length();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }
        is.close();
        file=null;




            String encString="";        
            int iFixedLen=110;
            if(bytes.length>=iFixedLen){

                int noOfBlocks=(int)Math.ceil((bytes.length/110.0));
            //  System.out.println("Noof blocks :"+noOfBlocks);
                for(int i=0;i<noOfBlocks;i++){
                    byte[] tempStr=null;
                    if(i==noOfBlocks-1){
                        //System.out.println("Last block");
                        tempStr=new byte[(bytes.length-(i*iFixedLen))];
                        System.arraycopy(bytes, (i*iFixedLen), tempStr, 0,(bytes.length-(i*iFixedLen)));
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        //System.out.println("i : "+i);
                        tempStr=new byte[iFixedLen];
                        //tempStr=new byte[iFixedLen];
                        System.arraycopy(bytes, (i*iFixedLen), tempStr, 0,iFixedLen);
                        //tempStr=plainText.substring(0,110) ;
                        //plainText=plainText.substring(110);
                    }
                    encString+= encryptBytes(tempStr,pubKey)+"    ";
                }
                encString=encString.substring(0,encString.length()-1);
                retval=noOfBlocks;
            }else{
                encString=encryptBytes(bytes,pubKey);
                retval=1;

            }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = AccessController.doPrivileged(
         new PrivilegedExceptionAction<FileOutputStream>() {
             public FileOutputStream run() throws FileNotFoundException {

                 return new FileOutputStream(location);
             }
         });
     } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
         throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getException();
     }
    fos.write(encString.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
return retval;
}
```

encryptBytes function followes :

```
public String encryptBytes(byte[] rawData,PublicKey pubkey){
        String retval=null;

       try{

        byte[] rawByteData=rawData;
        Cipher cp=Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        cp.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,pubkey);
        byte[] getDat=cp.doFinal(rawByteData);

        retval=java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getDat);

         }catch(Exception e)
         {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: There is a bug somewhere in your code. This can be said even without seeing it.

Comment: @Henry there is no problem with the simple text contents but in case of diagrams and tables its not working properly.

Comment: So there is a bug in your code when encrypting diagrams and tables. What other kind of an answer possibly be expecting?

Comment: Then how to encode decode text files containing those contents ?

Comment: @R.chow do it in the correct way.

Comment: @R.chow Same way you are encrypting the text, of course. You have that working: keep using it. Don't write different code. It's all binary. Unclear what the problem is, or what a text file containing diagrams or tables is, or what [tag:sign] has to do with it; unanswerable without seeing the code.

Comment: Most likely it is some encoding issue that only works on reading/writing bytes/binary data. As you have been told multiple times by now: we can't tell you without seeing your code. Please turn to the help center and read about minimal, complete, viable example ...

Comment: Your question is unclear. If a file is a *text* file, then the tables and diagrams in it are just characters that are ordered nicely. If you mean a *word processing document*, which has graphical tables and diagrams, then this is not a *text file*. Please [edit] your question and explain in detail: (1) What kind of text files you are referring to, preferably with a small example. (2) What code you are using. Don't describe the code ("I am using..."), but create a [mcve] and post it inside the question. (3) Explain what the exact results you are expecting are, and what you get instead.

Comment: I am new to posting in stack overflow so pardon if formatting and anything unimportant i have mentioned. Let me try with a clear snippet.

Comment: You shouldn't be using readers or writers on word-processing files. Stick to input and output streams. And **post your code.** Or see your question closed and deleted.

Comment: decryption follows the same way

Comment: You know that `available()` *doesn't* give you the length of the file, don't you? It just gives you how many bytes are available from the file at the moment without blocking. It's best not to try to read the whole file into memory in any case, but work on it chunk-by-chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You have made just about every mistake in the book here.

```
        InputStream is =  fis;
      //long length = file.length();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[fis.available()];
```

`InputStream.available()` is not an indicator of the length of the input stream. See the Javadoc, which contains a specific warning against exactly what you are doing here. You can practically always use a fixed size buffer when doing I/O of any kind, and it is rarely if ever necessary to read entire files into memory. Compilers don't do it: why should you?

```
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }
        is.close();
        file=null;
```

The `file = null;` statement is pointless here, and the entire loop can be elided as I will show below.

```
            String encString="";
```

`String` is not a container for binary data.

```
            int iFixedLen=110;
```

Where did the magic number `110` come from?

```
            if(bytes.length>=iFixedLen){

                int noOfBlocks=(int)Math.ceil((bytes.length/110.0));
            //  System.out.println("Noof blocks :"+noOfBlocks);
                for(int i=0;i<noOfBlocks;i++){
                    byte[] tempStr=null;
                    if(i==noOfBlocks-1){
                        //System.out.println("Last block");
                        tempStr=new byte[(bytes.length-(i*iFixedLen))];
                        System.arraycopy(bytes, (i*iFixedLen), tempStr, 0,(bytes.length-(i*iFixedLen)));
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        //System.out.println("i : "+i);
                        tempStr=new byte[iFixedLen];
                        //tempStr=new byte[iFixedLen];
                        System.arraycopy(bytes, (i*iFixedLen), tempStr, 0,iFixedLen);
                        //tempStr=plainText.substring(0,110) ;
                        //plainText=plainText.substring(110);
                    }
                    encString+= encryptBytes(tempStr,pubKey)+"    ";
                }
                encString=encString.substring(0,encString.length()-1);
                retval=noOfBlocks;
            }else{
                encString=encryptBytes(bytes,pubKey);
                retval=1;

            }
```

I have no idea what all this is supposed to be doing, but you should not be using blocks of 110 bytes, or characters, or whatever they are, or converting encrypted data in the form of a byte array to String, and you should not be appending four spaces to it.

```
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = AccessController.doPrivileged(
         new PrivilegedExceptionAction<FileOutputStream>() {
             public FileOutputStream run() throws FileNotFoundException {

                 return new FileOutputStream(location);
             }
         });
     } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
         throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getException();
     }
    fos.write(encString.getBytes());
```

Here you could just have written the original byte array resulting from the actual encryption and avoided the whole problem.

You haven't posted the `encryptBytes()` method so it is impossible to comment further.

```
    fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
return retval;
}
```

Comment: the function encryptBytes() returns string value of the encrypted data .

Comment: The "magic number" 110 comes from a wrong way of trying to work around the fact that not all RSA chunks have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a file contains tables or other structures is completely irrelevant for modern encryption, because it works on binary data which is already serialized from the "document".

You're trying to apply RSA for some chunks of the original file. This is very tricky to get right, because you have to make sure that the input is smaller than the RSA modulus taking the padding into account. Then you have to make sure that each ciphertext chunk has exactly the same length so that you know which bytes belong to which chunk during decryption. In RSA it is not guaranteed that the output will always have the same number of bytes. It can be smaller compared to the padded input. So you would need to pad the ciphertext chunks consistently.

A better idea would be to use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). You could use AES to encrypt the actual data and use RSA to encrypt the randomly generated AES key. A simple format should be easy to do:

```
4 bytes - Length of the RSA-encrypted AES key (= x)
x bytes - RSA-encrypted AES key
remaining bytes - AES-encrypted file
```

Of course, if you're doing AES encryption, you would have to think about the mode of operation, the padding mode, how to handle the initialization vector and whether you want to add authenticated encryption.

Comment: may be for 110 division the padding space i added that is doing the anamoly..well thanks Artjom I will look in to the hybrid encryption.

Comment: but symmetric key have the hindrance to share the key to all but in my case that is not suitable enough. Can you please help me in padding more efficiently ?(in this case)

Comment: No, you misunderstood. The AES key will only be recoverable by the person that is holding the private RSA key.